# JSF Tag exception caused by f:setPropertyActionListener: Parent is not of type ActionSource

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, icefaces

I have a web application written in plain old JSF that I want partially migrate to ICEfaces to use some of its components, namely confirmation panel for now. To use it, I changed my forms with links that require confirmation to ice: tag library from h:. Links I use should fire method that takes a parameter. The parameter is sent via f:setPropertyActionListener. However, now I get the following exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: 
/jsp/manageDomainTypes.xhtml @30,99 <f:setPropertyActionListener> 
Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: 
javax.faces.component.UIOutput@14ea0724
```

If I switch back to h taglib, exception disappears and everything works fine. Where am I wrong and What can I do to properly use my command links in ICEfaces? I use Tomcat 6.0.26 with JSF 2.0 and ICEfaces 2.0.0 alpha3 onboard.

One example of such a link is:

```
<ice:commandLink action="#{DomainTypeBean.openEditDomainType}">
    <ice:graphicImage value="#{icon.edit}"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
        target="#{DomainTypeBean.currentType}" value="#{domainType}" />
</ice:commandLink>
```

Links are nested into

```
<ui:define><ice:form><ice:panelGrid><ice:dataTable>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icefaces [`HtmlCommandLink`](http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/icefaces/trunk/icefaces/component/src/com/icesoft/faces/component/ext/HtmlCommandLink.java) extends the original one, so the problem is not in the component.

I'd assume you have incorrectly imported the and the icefaces component is not resolved.

Comment: Can you suggest any reading about proper importing? What I did was just converting pages to facelets, adding icefaces library and switching to ice: tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. It arised because to use ice: tags in ICEfaces 2.0, compatibility libraries are to be included for substituting the components with ICEfaces 1.8.2 ones as ICEfaces 2.0 components are still under development.